# CVS says it knows nothing of a file it checked out

Tags: cvs

I was trying to get the History of file from Tortoise CVS and i was getting the below error

```
cvs log: nothing known about [filename]
```

What should i be doing to resolve this, i did a fresh checkout and these files do come as part of the checkout, but any other workflow activity on them like log, remove etc does not work.

Comment: Please post the exact command you typed in.

Comment: Tortoise CVS was using the following command

cvs.exe -q -f log [filename]

Comment: What version of cvs? Did you do a compile first? Try a cvs status on the file.  The error message usually means that there is nothing in the repository with that name/path.  Can you look at the repository? Do you see the local CVS directory where the file lives?

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue because of a conflict in case names of directories, our CVS Repository was in Unix, so when two different team memebers created dirs named js and JS in different branches, it caused quite a bit of confusion on the client side which is Windows.

I resolved the issue by checking out the repository in Linux, deleting the file from one of the dirs, and asking the CVS Admin to physically delete the directory from the CVS Repository itself.

Comment: I don't think my issue is exactly this. Our server is hosted on a Linux machine, but the file is one in the middle of a thousand in an SDK package. It is static, we use CVS just as a mean to synchronize